# Why does Flow warn me that my returned promise is uncovered?

Tags: javascript, types, promise, axios, flowtype

I'm developing a web application using React, and want add types with Flow.

The GET method is part of my service interface class. The class has methods like `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc. The methods return an axios promise which will be used somewhat like this:

```
import Interface from './interface'
const api = new Interface();
export const service = {
    users: () => { return api.GET('users') },
    //...more endpoints
}
```

Why do I get a warning from Flow, that the code underlined in green is "uncovered"?

[image: How do I get rid of "uncovered code" warning?]

Comment: What is flow? The flow tag says "This is a meta tag and should not be used. See the wiki for more information."

Comment: @Goose https://flow.org/en/

Comment: The tag to use is: flowtype

Answer (score 1):

Could be an issue with Flow itself:

https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode/issues/138